# What is the type external auth(wallet) for a function in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I know what is external type in solidity functions but this is new to me: external auth(wallet) sometime without (wallet) argument is only displayed as external auth. What does it means? or can it be used without external? Just as auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth()` isn’t a standard Solidity modifier like `external`, and is probably a [function modifier](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#function-modifiers) that is specific to the contract you are inspecting. Solidity lets you create custom modifiers, e.g. the `Ownable` contract in the openzeppelin-contracts library [defines](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.4.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L42-L45) a custom `onlyOwner` modifier, which may then be used (by itself and by extending contracts) to “mark” functions as being only callable by the contract owner.